# Raspberry piにimg書き込み後、SDカードが認識されない

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry piにraspbianのimgを書き込みました。
書き込み後一度もスロットからSDを抜き差ししないうちは中身がみれたのですが、一度はずしたところ「フォーマットしますか」と表示されるようになってしまいました。
そこで、SDFormatterを使いフォーマット。認識は可能になりましたが、容量が16GBから40MBとなってしまいました。
こちら(http://qiita.com/tamamius/items/26f37dad9ed711f46533)
を参考に作業しましたが解決せず困っております。

Comment: そのページを参考にして実行した diskpart に入力したコマンドと、その時の出力を、まるっとコピペして質問に追加されるとよろしいかと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。現在手元にPCがないため申し訳ありませんが、明日また追記させていただきますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDFormatterのフォーマットオプションに「論理サイズ調整」という設定が見当たらないでしょうか？

これをONにしてフォーマットを行ってみてください。

[image: SDFormatter]

Raspbianを書き込んだSDカードは、先頭に50MB前後のパーティションが作られます。Raspbianを起動すると、この先頭のパーティションが `/boot` にマウントされ、残りが `/` にマウントされます。Raspbianからはそう見えるのですが、そのカードをWindowsに戻すと先頭パーティションだけが認識されるため、カード全体を再び使えるようにするには、パーティションテーブルごと初期化する必要があり、それを行うのが、SDFormatterの「論理サイズ調整 ON」です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それがその方法も試しております。もう一度試してみましたがダメでした。

Comment: 本日、他のSDにも書き込んでみたのですが同じように一度SDを作業用のWindowsから抜くとアクセスができなくなってしまうのです。

Comment: ext4のドライバを使えば読み書きが可能になるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

解決致しました。
別のPCでフォーマットしたところフォーマットが出来ました。
なぜそうなったのかは分かりませんが、単純なミスで申し訳ありません。
お二方ともありがとうございました。